# Is it necessary to override bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options: in an NSView subclass to implement binding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSView subclass which has property which I want to be bindable. I've implemented the following in the subclass:

myView.h:

```
@property (readwrite, retain) NSArray *representedObjects;
```

myView.m:

```
@synthesize representedObjects;

+(void)initialize
{
    [self exposeBinding: @"representedObjects"];
}


-(void)bind:(NSString *)binding toObject:(id)observableController withKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath options:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    if ([binding isEqualToString:@"representedObjects"]) {
        [observableController addObserver: self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey context:nil];
    } else {
        [super bind: binding toObject:observableController withKeyPath:keyPath options: options];
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"arrangedObjects"]) {
        [self setRepresentedObjects: [object arrangedObjects]];
    }
}
```

I then create the binding to an arrayController in `-[AppController awakeFromNib]`:

```
[myView bind:@"representedObjects" toObject:arrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options: nil];
```

Is this the correct way of implementing binding? It involves a lot of boiler plate code which makes me think that I'm doing something wrong.

I thought that NSObject would automagically implement what I have done manually in `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` but this doesn't seem to be the case. If I comment out my `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` the setRepresentedObjects method is never called.

Additional info:
I've done some more investigating and have reached the conclusion that my original approach is correct and you do have to over ride `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:`. Here's a quote from [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics: How Do Bindings Work?](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373):

> In its bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options: method an object must as a minimum do the following:
>
> - Determine which binding is being set
> - Record what object it is being bound to using what keypath and with what options
> - Register as an observer of the keypath of the object to which it is bound so that it receives notification of changes
>
> The code sample in Listing 2 shows a partial implementation of Joystick’s bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options: method dealing with just the angle binding.
>
> Listing 2  Partial implementation of the bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options method for the Joystick class:
>
> > ```
> > static void *AngleBindingContext = (void *)@"JoystickAngle";
> >  
> > - (void)bind:(NSString *)binding
> >  toObject:(id)observableObject
> >  withKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
> >  options:(NSDictionary *)options
> > {
> >  // Observe the observableObject for changes -- note, pass binding identifier
> >  // as the context, so you get that back in observeValueForKeyPath:...
> >  // This way you can easily determine what needs to be updated.
> >  
> > if ([binding isEqualToString:@"angle"])
> >  {
> >     [observableObject addObserver:self
> >                    forKeyPath:keyPath
> >                   options:0
> >                   context:AngleBindingContext];
> >  
> >     // Register what object and what keypath are
> >     // associated with this binding
> >     observedObjectForAngle = [observableObject retain];
> >     observedKeyPathForAngle = [keyPath copy];
> >  
> >     // Record the value transformer, if there is one
> >     angleValueTransformer = nil;
> >     NSString *vtName = [options objectForKey:@"NSValueTransformerName"];
> >     if (vtName != nil)
> >     {
> >         angleValueTransformer = [NSValueTransformer
> >             valueTransformerForName:vtName];
> >     }
> >  }
> >  // Implementation continues...
> > ```

This clearly shows that the Joystick class (which is an NSView subclass) needs to override `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:`.

I find this surprising. I was skeptical of this conclusion as I have found no other code samples that do this. However, as the offical Apple documentation says I should over ride `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` I conclude that it is the correct approach.

I would be very happy if someone could prove me wrong!

Comment: Related question with more activity, on bindings with two-way updates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169097/can-you-manually-implement-cocoa-bindings

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn’t need that glue code.

What do you mean by “doesn’t seem to be the case”? What happens if you omit it?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not necessary to override `bind:`.

As Peter Hosey wrote in the comment to the earlier answer, you can call `exposeBinding:` and implement KVC- and KVO-compliant accessors and setters.

**MyView.h:**

```
@interface MyView : NSView {
    NSArray *_representedObjects;
}

// IBOutlet is not required for bindings, but by adding it you can ALSO use
// an outlet
@property (readonly, retain) IBOutlet NSArray *representedObjects;

@end
```

**MyView.m:**

```
+ (void)initialize {
    [self exposeBinding:@"representedObjects"];
}

// Use a custom setter, because presumably, the view needs to re-draw
- (void)setRepresentedObjects:(NSArray *)representedObjects {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"representedObjects"];
    // Based on automatic garbage collection
    _representedObjects = representedObjects;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"representedObjects"];

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:[self visibleRect]];
}
```

Then you can set the binding programmatically:

```
[myView bind:@"representedObjects" toObject:arrayController withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options: nil];
```

To set the binding in Interface Builder, however, you must create a custom palette.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely DO need to implement `-bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` in a custom view if you want to implement bindings in that view. Your implementation in myView.m is pretty much spot on.

Comment: No, you don't. You only need to call exposeBinding: and implement KVC- and KVO-compliant accessors for each bindable property. @property and @synthesize do the latter part for you.

Comment: Interesting, you're right. I've always done it the long-winded way, so I'm off to delete some code.